# AVG Free Anti Virus - do not track, but who is good / bad?

Tags: anti-virus, avg-antivirus

The recent version of AVG free features "do not track". There are Ad and Analytic networks I can disable in my browser. **Basically I like this feature**.

What I wonder is, **how do I decide who are the good and the bad guys**? The Analytic networks (such as Google / Yahoo Analytics) are enabled by default. OK, understood.

But how come that some of the Ad networks are enabled by default, some are disabled. How can I tell which Ad network I shall enable (ie support), and who has a bad reputation. Is there a white list, black list or something I can base my decision on?

And how can AVG provide such a default list, based on what decision / facts?

[image: AVG Free - do not track options]

Comment: Its a voluntary system, they can track you even if you opt out, do not track is worthless imho.

Comment: As I understand it, AVG blocks any information send to these networks and additionally sends the DNT Header. The latter might be worthless, but inhibiting the cookie is not. Or am I wrong here?

Comment: It cannot block all information, or you would not be able to display the webpage, cookies can be stored in several different places on your pc and there are different types of cookies, I don't know how effective AVG is at keeping them all cleaned up or blocked. Cookies are only one of many methods used to track you.

Comment: Good input, thx.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to simply **block them all**.  If you find some websites do not function correctly afterwards, you can then determine what ad networks to re-enable.

Comment: Websites functionality cannot be hampered by Ad and analytics trackers.

Comment: As of the comment of Moab above I am not sure how AVG actually works, are the tracker cookies just blocked or send and cleaned up afterwards? Sometimes I have noticed a web page is not displaying because it still waits for an Ad website's response.